# Bind data to a ListBox inside another ListBox in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I really need help on this. I have been stuck on this for the past week.

I want to show Data in a ListBox inside another ListBox. The First ListBox works properly and data is properly Loaded into that ListBox. But the problem comes when I try to Bind Data in the Second ListBox.

Here is the ListBox that I have:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Margin="0,14,0,0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myAutoComplete, Path=FilteredSuggestions}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >

                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid Margin="0, 12, 0, 12" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="32" x:Name="Abc" Grid.Column="1" Margin="12,6,12,6" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,24">

                            <ListBox x:Name="myWorking" IsHitTestVisible="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding ProdDesc}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="37,6">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Width="87" Height="87" Source="Images/Product.png"/>
                                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                                <TextBlock Margin="12,-9,12,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>

                                            <Border Margin="0,9,0,12" BorderThickness="0,0,0,12" BorderBrush="#55555555" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                            </Border>

                                            <Border Margin="0,-41,0,12" BorderThickness="0,0,0,8" BorderBrush="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                    <CompositeTransform SkewX="-40" />
                                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                                            </Border>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>


            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want to Add Data in the ListBox named **myWorking**

But when I try to Add Code from C# or Bind in XAML, no data is Loaded.

Here is the Code that I have done so far in C# end.

I have created a class named **Prod_Description**:

```
class Prod_Description : INotifyPropertyProdged
{
    public event PropertyProdgedEventHandler PropertyProdged;
    public void OnPropertyProdged(PropertyProdgedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyProdged != null)
            PropertyProdged(this, e);
    }


    public int _productid;
    public int ProductId
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _productid; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if (_productid != value)
            {
                _productid = value;
                OnPropertyProdged(new PropertyProdgedEventArgs("ProductId"));
            }
        }
    }



    public string _productname;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _productname; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (_productname != value)
            {
                _productname = value;
                OnPropertyProdged(new PropertyProdgedEventArgs("ProductName"));
            }
        }
    }


    public string _productlink;
    public string ProductLink
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _productlink; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (_productlink != value)
            {
                _productlink = value;
                OnPropertyProdged(new PropertyProdgedEventArgs("ProductLink"));
            }
        }
    }


    public string _categoryname;
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _categoryname; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (_categoryname != value)
            {
                _categoryname = value;
                OnPropertyProdged(new PropertyProdgedEventArgs("CategoryName"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Prod_Description(string prodname, string proddesc, string catname)
    {
        this._productname = prodname;
        this._productlink = proddesc;
        this._categoryname = catname;
    }
```

And in my **MainPage.xaml.cs**, I have written the following Code:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Chan_Description> ProdDesc = new ObservableCollection<Prod_Description>();
```

And in my **PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded** method:

```
        foreach (Pr_Description prod_Items in pr_DescriptionList) // pr_DescriptionList is a List where all the Items are stored
        {
            this.ProdDesc.Add(new Prod_Description(prod_Items.ProductName,prod_Items.ProductLink,prod_Items.CategoryName));
        }


        myAutoComplete.SuggestionsSource = ProdDesc;


        this.myAutoComplete.FilterKeyProvider = (object item) =>
        {
            return  ((item as Prod_Description).ProductName + (item as Prod_Description).ProductName);
        };
```

I really don't know what I am missing in here. I have searched Internet a lot but failed to find any answer to this problem.

So, my question is, how can I Bind ItemsSource in **myWorking** ListBox? I want to Bind the **ProdDesc** ObservableCollection in **myWorking** ListBox. Thanks.

Comment: You may try to make FilteredSuggestions as a dictionary, where key will be your ProductName and value will be your collection of Prod_Description. In the inner list box you can bind data as FilteredSuggestions.value. Hope it helps

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I have never used FilteredSuggestion. @gusaindpk